# Skype shows me "away" as soon as I close application

Tags: skype

Today I noticed a strange Skype behaviour:

It reflects user status change in other Skype clients of other users properly, but as soon as I close Skype or kill Skype process intentionally (to not allow it to send data to login server) I appear as "away" for my contacts instead of "offline".

Is it a bug or a feature related to the fact that all the data goes now through Microsoft servers? (some kind of "voicemail" and "chatmail"?)

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you mean that you had invisible set, and then ending skype caused you to go online?   If so, I would check to see if you are logged in via another device, perhaps a phone?

Comment: Tyson, exactly. I am invisible, and terminating Skype makes me go to "away" status.

Comment: You might want to edit the invisible fact into the question.  I predict your logged in on another device though.

Comment: I have the opposite program.  80% of my friends list is people who are "away"...who haven't been online in months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I left a logged in Skype instance on some device.

Two chat commands:

```
/showplaces
```

and

```
/remotelogout
```

did the job for me. All other Skype instances were forced to log out and the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you've enabled your Skype account on another device, such as your phone.

1.Change your password 
2. connect on your desktop account, 
3. logout and check if the problem persists.

There is no option to logout from all devices from all I know.